# How to kill line in Terminal and yank it into Emacs buffer?

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, kill, yank

I know I can kill current line text by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> in Terminal(Terminal.app). I want to know how to yank it to  Emacs.

For example:

```
|------+-----------------+--------------|
| step | action          | where        |
|------+-----------------+--------------|
|    1 | Type "ABC"      | Terminal.app |
|    2 | C-a             | Terminal.app |
|    3 | C-k             | Terminal.app |
|    4 | Switch to Emacs |              |
|    5 | C-y             | Emacs        |
|------+-----------------+--------------|
```

In above example step 5, I just want Emacs paste "ABC" into its emacs-buffer. Help me.

Oh, I forgot to say that I do NOT want to `select text by mouse` and press `Command-c`.

Comment: Is using `shell-mode` and option ?

Comment: @Ehvince: I want to paste text killed in "Terminal.app(not Emacs `shell-mode`)" to "Emacs". It's not direct answer though, using `shell-mode` may be one of the approach to my question.

Comment: Ctrl-k in the terminal is handled by the process running in the terminal, not by `Terminal.app`. There is no cross-process clipboard in the terminal as such (i.e. the VT102 that your shell runs within).

Comment: @molbdnilo: I didn't know that. Then it seems not possible to set osx's clipboard by Ctrl-k in pure OS X Terminal.app. So using `shell-mode` In Emacs seems realistic answer.

Comment: If shell-mode is an option then super-cool ! I use exactly for that: everything is all text, I can use Emacs as always to parse the result of my shell commands. Super-useful when I run tests, compilations, etc. See http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but I get a line from the Terminal into emacs using echo and pbcopy like this:

```
Type your text
> ABCD 
Ctrl-A echo
> echo ABCD
Ctrl-E | pbcopy ENTER
> echo ABCD | pbcopy
```

Now you can paste into emacs

Comment: Great! It's no need to use mouse. And moreover I can train finger mussels.